# Multiple activities in one tab

Tags: android

I want to navigate through the multiple activities in one tab. All I see is solutions with ActivityGroup but it is deprecated. How to do this with Fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewFlipper is Best possible option in your case

Invest your time in reading [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69008/Android-ViewFlipper-Touch-Animation-like-News-Weat).

In ViewFlipper you can have multiple pages and you can navigate between them using 
ShowNext and ShowPrevious method.

Hope this Helps

Comment: I think you are right...God, how this simple operation could be so difficult? Just trying to do the same navigation as I have in my iOS app.